# How do I prove that $3^n - 3$ is never a square number?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, square-numbers, perfect-powers

Prove that there do not exist positive integers $a$ and $n$ such that $a^2 + 3 = 3^n$.

I have tried writing the equation in another way: $a^2 = 3^n - 3 = 3(3^{n-1} -1)$ but that doesn't get me anywhere. Should I consider different cases such as $a$ and $n$ being odd, $a$ and $n$ being even, etc.?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First, you can notice that $a\equiv 0\mod 3$. That said, you now know that $a=3k$, meaning you need to prove that there do not exist positive integers $k$ and $n$ such that

$$9k^2 + 3 = 3^n$$

Or, dividing by $3$:
$$3k^2 + 1 = 3^{n-1}$$

Can you do the final step?

EDIT:

You can also continue what you started:

$$a^2=3(3^{n-1} - 1)$$

From this equation, you can see that $a^2$ must be divisible by $3$, and because it is a perfect square, it must be divisible by $9$, which is impossible.

Comment: I liked your approach to the problem--I actually didn't consider using the rules of divisibility. However, for the second approach you posted, do you mind explaining why a must be divisible by 9? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Actually I like the second method better. And not just because it builds on what OP already found.

Comment: @LindaKallash If there is no factor of $3$ in $a$, then there is no factor of $3$ in $a\cdot a = a^2$. But if there _is_ a factor of $3$ in $a$, that is, $a = 3b$, then $a^2 = (3b^2) = 9b^2,$ so there is a factor of $9$ in $a^2$.

Comment: @LindaKallash Well, $a^2$ is divisible by $3$, so, because $3$ is prime, $a$ must be divisible by $3$. This means $a=3k$, so $a^2=9k^2$, so $a^2$ is divisible by $9$.

Comment: @LindaKallash It's even more general: any time you have a perfect square which is divisible by a prime number, it must also be divisible by the square of that prime number.

Comment: @DavidK Yeah, I prefer the second way also. Technically, the two "methods" are almost identical, but it is much easier to see what is going on in the second approach.

Comment: @5xum I apologize for bothering you with this question again, but why is it impossible for a^2 to be divisible by 9?

Comment: @LindaKallash, is $3^{n-1}-1$ divisible by $3$?

Answer (score 4):

First note that $n=1$ gives $a=0$, which, while square, is not positive as required. So $n$ must be greater than $1$.

Proceeding to search for a contradiction, assume that we can find $a^2 = 3^n-3 = 3(3^{n-1} -1)$, so we would need $3 \mid a^2$. Since $3$ is prime, this would mean that $3 \mid a$ and we can find integer $k$ such that $a=3k$.

However that gives $3k^2 = (3^{n-1}-1)$, requiring $3 \mid (3^{n-1}-1)$ which is not true - a contradiction which shows that there is no such $a$ and that $3^n-3$ cannot be the square of a positive number.

Answer (score 2):

You would need $3\mid3^{n-1}-1$, and this cannot occur if $n > 1$.